# Get malware security feeds, and output to file

Tags: python, python-2.x

The idea is that local security/SIEM solutions want to populate their database with information gathered from different security feeds. This is done through importing and monitoring .txt files (for some reason).

The idea behind this, is that I want each feed to have their own function, to easier be able to filter out, or add new feeds. Not to mention that almost every feed has it's own format.

The output of all this, needs to be in the current format, which is:

> ```
> IP [FEED NAME]
>
> DOMAIN [FEED NAME]
> ```

I am sure there are better ways, especially to generate the .txt file outputs.

The idea is that the script is to be run by itself, without any input, in a cron file, and if something has to be changed, the script itself should be edited.

All feeds are directly available for everyone, so if you are curious about any formats, the URLs are in the script, with the exception of the first feed (OTX), which needs you to sign up, if needed I can paste a output from this feed.

So, you can copy and paste this script in and run it out of the box, except you might want to comment out `get_alienvault`.

**Questions:**

- Due to that every feed has a different format, I am guessing there would be no way for me to have one function that goes through all feeds, or does someone see a way?
- I am sure the output can be heavily modified, at a later date, I was thinking of either outputting to .txt, or use the CSV lib to writerows the same way I do now with the txt files.

  - Do I need the main method? Or is there a better way to call all the different functions? Maybe with the possibility to ignore something in the future? Without commenting out the function call?
- The systems that will be importing this are very sensitive to extra whitespaces and so, currently using lstrip/rstrip for this, and `splitlines()`. Any better way?

Script:

```py
import requests
import re
from OTXv2 import OTXv2
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Defines the list that is going to populate the different feeds
d = defaultdict(list)

# Your API key for OTX. If you do not have any, please comment out
# "get_alienvault" in the main function.
otx = OTXv2("XXXXX")


class GetFeeds(object):
    """
    Main class to gather and output feed results
    """

    def download_file(self, url):
        """
        Download the feeds specified
        :param url: The location of the source to download
        :return The content of the request
        """

        r = requests.get(url)
        return r.content

    def ipgrabber(self, results):
        """
        :param reults: The results that should be filtered
        :return: Only the IP addresses from the object it filtered out
        """

        ip = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', results)
        return ip

    def get_alienvault(self, days):
        """
        Gets the information from Alienvault OTX
        :param days: How many days the reslts from the feed can be
        :return: The IP addresses and domains returned from OTX
        """

        mtime = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=days)).isoformat()

        pulses = otx.getsince(mtime)

        # Populate the list with the returned results from OTX
        for index, feeds in enumerate(pulses):
            for pulse in pulses[index]['indicators']:
                if pulse['type'] == 'IPv4':
                    d['alienvaultip'].append(pulse['indicator'])
                elif pulse['type'] == 'URL':
                    d['alienvaulturl'].append(pulse['indicator'])
                elif pulse['type'] == 'domain':
                    d['alienvaultdomain'].append(pulse['indicator'])
        return d

    def get_malc0de(self):
        """
        Gets the information from the Malc0de Feed
        :return: The IP addresses returned from Malc0de
        """

        url = 'http://malc0de.com/bl/IP_Blacklist.txt'
        results = self.download_file(url).splitlines()
        for result in results:
            if len(result) > 0:
                ip = self.ipgrabber(result.lstrip().rstrip())
                if ip:
                    d['malc0deip'].append(result)
        return d

    def get_talosintel(self):
        """
        Gets the information from the TalosIntel Feed
        :return: The IP addresses returned from TalosIntel
        """

        url = 'http://www.talosintelligence.com/feeds/ip-filter.blf'
        results = self.download_file(url).splitlines()
        for result in results:
            if len(result) > 0:
                ip = self.ipgrabber(result.lstrip().rstrip())
                if ip:
                    d['talosintelip'].append(result)
        return d

    def get_malwaredomainlist(self):
        """
        Gets the information from the MDL Feed
        :return: The IP addresses and domains returned from MDL
        """

        url = 'http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/ip.txt'
        domains = 'http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt'
        results = self.download_file(url).splitlines()
        results2 = self.download_file(domains).splitlines()
        for result in results:
            if len(result) > 0:
                ip = self.ipgrabber(result.lstrip().rstrip())
                if ip:
                    d['malwaredomainlistip'].append(result)
        for result in results2:
            result = result.lstrip('127.0.0.1  , ').rstrip()
            if not result.startswith('#') \
                    and not result.startswith('localhost') and len(result) > 0:
                d['malwaredomainlistdomain'].append(result)
        return d

    def get_tornodes(self):
        """
        Gets the information from the Torproject overview
        :return: The IP addresses of the current TOR exit nodes
        """

        url = 'https://check.torproject.org/exit-addresses'
        results = self.download_file(url).splitlines()
        for result in results:
            if len(results) > 0:
                ip = self.ipgrabber(result.lstrip().rstrip())
                if ip:
                    d['tornodeip'].append(ip)
        return d

    def get_ransomwaretracker(self):
        """
        Gets the information from the RansomewareTracker Feed
        :return: The IP addresses returned from RansomewareTracker
        """

        url = 'https://ransomwaretracker.abuse.ch/feeds/csv/'
        results = self.download_file(url).splitlines()
        for result in results:
            if len(result) > 0:
                ip = self.ipgrabber(result.lstrip().rstrip())
                for singleip in ip:
                    d['ransomwaretrackerip'].append(singleip)
        for result in results:
            if re.search(r'\"online\"', result):
                for url in re.findall(r',\"\w+\.\w+\"', result):
                    url = re.sub(',"', '\"', url)
                    url = re.sub('"', '', url)
                    d['ransomewaretrackerdomain'].append(url)
        return d

    def get_bambenek(self):
        """
        Gets the information from the RansomewareTracker Feed
        :return: The IP addresses and domains returned from Bambenek
        """

        url = 'https://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/feeds/c2-ipmasterlist.txt'
        domains = 'http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/feeds/c2' \
                  '-dommasterlist.txt'
        results = self.download_file(url).splitlines()
        results2 = self.download_file(domains).splitlines()
        for result in results:
            if len(result) > 0:
                ip = self.ipgrabber(result.lstrip().rstrip())
                if ip:
                    d['bambenekip'].append(ip)
        for result in results2:
            if not result.startswith('#') \
                    and not result.startswith('localhost') and len(result) > 0:
                url = result.split(",")[0]
                d['bambenekdomain'].append(url)
        return d

    # Executes the downloading and parsing of feeds
    def main(self):
        self.get_malc0de()
        self.get_alienvault(10)
        self.get_talosintel()
        self.get_malwaredomainlist()
        self.get_tornodes()
        self.get_bambenek()
        self.get_ransomwaretracker()

        # Export IP Addresses to txt file, tagged with their sources
        f = open("iplist.txt", "w")
        iplist = d['ransomwaretrackerip']
        f.write(
            "".join("{}\t[Ransomewaretracker]\n".format(t) for t in iplist))
        iplist = d['bambenekip']
        f.write("".join("{}\t[Bambenek]\n".format(t) for t in iplist))
        iplist = d['alienvaultip']
        f.write("".join("{}\t[AlienVault]\n".format(t) for t in iplist))
        iplist = d['malc0deip']
        f.write("".join("{}\t[Malc0de]\n".format(t) for t in iplist))
        iplist = d['talosintelip']
        f.write("".join("{}\t[TalosIntel]\n".format(t) for t in iplist))
        iplist = d['malwaredomainlistip']
        f.write("".join("{}\t[MalwareDomainList]\n".format(t) for t in iplist))
        f.close()

        # Export domains to txt file, tagged with their sources
        f = open("domainlist.txt", "w")
        domainlist = d['ransomwaretrackerdomain']
        f.write("".join(
            "{}\t[Ransomewaretracker]\n".format(t) for t in domainlist))
        domainlist = d['bambenekdomain']
        f.write("".join("{}\t[Bambenek]\n".format(t) for t in domainlist))
        domainlist = d['alienvaultdomain']
        f.write("".join("{}\t[AlienVault]\n".format(t) for t in domainlist))
        domainlist = d['malwaredomainlistdomain']
        f.write(
            "".join("{}\t[MalwareDomainList]\n".format(t) for t in domainlist))
        f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    o = GetFeeds()
    o.main()
```

As output was requested, here is one output per feed:

This is one entry for `get_alienvault`, there will be many arrays of "industries":

> ```
> [
>   {
>     u'industries': [
>
>     ],
>     u'TLP': u'green',
>     u'description': u'Analysis of HackingTeam Android malware',
>     u'created': u'2016-11-15T03:10:51.515000',
>     u'tags': [
>       u'android',
>       u'hackingteam',
>       u'hacking team',
>       u'apk',
>       u'mobile',
>       u'spyware'
>     ],
>     u'modified': u'2016-11-15T03:10:51.515000',
>     u'author_name': u'AlienVault',
>     u'public': True,
>     u'references': [
>       u'http://rednaga.io/2016/11/14/hackingteam_back_for_your_androids/'
>     ],
>     u'targeted_countries': [
>
>     ],
>     u'indicators': [
>       {
>         u'indicator': u'e362a037e70517565d28ab85959e6c9d231b2baf0c2df3b87dfaa1451278e80c',
>         u'description': u'',
>         u'title': u'',
>         u'created': u'2016-11-15T03:10:53',
>         u'content': u'',
>         u'type': u'FileHash-SHA256',
>         u'id': 1398126
>       },
>       {
>         u'indicator': u'07278c56973d609caa5f9eb2393d9b1eb41964d24e7e9e7a7e7f9fdfb2bb4c31',
>         u'description': u'',
>         u'title': u'',
>         u'created': u'2016-11-15T03:10:53',
>         u'content': u'',
>         u'type': u'FileHash-SHA256',
>         u'id': 1398127
>       },
>       {
>         u'indicator': u'ed33b83be3af715d3fd8ba6ac8b2b551a16697c5a37a9fcebfc40a024cc9b818',
>         u'description': u'',
>         u'title': u'',
>         u'created': u'2016-11-15T03:10:53',
>         u'content': u'',
>         u'type': u'FileHash-SHA256',
>         u'id': 1398128
>       },
>       {
>         u'indicator': u'4308286905ee3d3dd1f4171da15050d1672dcc63bfc65e012b18938275e96085',
>         u'description': u'',
>         u'title': u'',
>         u'created': u'2016-11-15T03:10:53',
>         u'content': u'',
>         u'type': u'FileHash-SHA256',
>         u'id': 1398129
>       },
>       {
>         u'indicator': u'87efe6a1cbf4d4481c6fa6e2c70a26a0b50a460557a1ad876af9966a571f8a4c',
>         u'description': u'',
>         u'title': u'',
>         u'created': u'2016-11-15T03:10:53',
>         u'content': u'',
>         u'type': u'FileHash-SHA256',
>         u'id': 1398130
>       },
>       {
>         u'indicator': u'68.233.237.11',
>         u'description': u'',
>         u'title': u'',
>         u'created': u'2016-11-15T03:10:53',
>         u'content': u'',
>         u'type': u'IPv4',
>         u'id': 1398131
>       },
>       {
>         u'indicator': u'66.232.100.221',
>         u'description': u'',
>         u'title': u'',
>         u'created': u'2016-11-15T03:10:53',
>         u'content': u'',
>         u'type': u'IPv4',
>         u'id': 1398132
>       }
>     ],
>     u'revision': 1.0,
>     u'adversary': u'HackingTeam',
>     u'id': u'582a7cbbc9eef92d31ad7c90',
>     u'name': u'HackingTeam back for your Androids'
>   },
>   {
> ```

Format for get_malc0de
[Malc0detxt](http://malc0de.com/bl/IP_Blacklist.txt):

> ```
> // This file will be automatically updated daily and populated with the last 30 days of malicious IP addresses.
> // Last updated 2016-11-15    
>
> 103.234.36.75
> 59.45.79.75
> 176.103.55.73
> 108.41.24.140
> 52.84.125.228
> 54.230.193.237
> 54.230.193.52
> 198.143.138.155
> 59.188.68.200
> 222.163.80.69
> 122.225.98.197
> 58.218.211.250
> 61.147.204.48
> 95.131.28.244
> 45.79.194.109
> 193.238.153.44
> 153.196.238.158
> 209.90.88.131
> 94.23.26.102
> 79.127.127.67
> 193.238.153.90
> 189.113.175.249
> 46.28.67.156
> 193.238.153.106
> ```

Format for get_talosintel
[Talostxt](http://www.talosintelligence.com/feeds/ip-filter.blf):

> ```
> 119.29.132.114
> 1.169.224.242
> 151.97.190.239
> 188.247.135.58
> 216.176.100.240
> 109.127.8.242
> 188.219.154.228
> 216.215.112.149
> 188.247.135.74
> 188.247.135.53
> 188.247.135.99
> 83.69.233.121
> 203.170.193.23
> 109.229.36.65
> ```

Format for get_malwaredomainlist:
IP addresses
[MDLtxtfile](http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/ip.txt)

> ```
> 103.14.120.121
> 103.19.89.55
> 103.224.212.222
> 103.31.186.207
> 103.31.186.29
> 103.4.16.91
> 103.4.218.22
> 103.6.196.156
> 103.8.127.189
> 103.8.127.205
> 104.152.215.90
> 104.245.239.7
> ```

Domains:
[MDLdomainstxt](http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt)

> ```
> #               MalwareDomainList.com Hosts List           #
> #   http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt   #
> #         Last updated: Fri, 11 Nov 16 06:02:27 +0000      #
>
>
> 127.0.0.1  localhost
> 127.0.0.1  0koryu0.easter.ne.jp
> 127.0.0.1  109-204-26-16.netconnexion.managedbroadband.co.uk
> 127.0.0.1  11.lamarianella.info
> 127.0.0.1  1866809.securefastserver.com
> 127.0.0.1  2amsports.com
> 127.0.0.1  3.bluepointmortgage.com
> 127.0.0.1  3.coolerpillow.com
> 127.0.0.1  4.androidislamic.com
> 127.0.0.1  4.collecorvino.org
> 127.0.0.1  4.dlevo.com
> 127.0.0.1  4.e-why.net
> 127.0.0.1  4.newenergydata.biz
> 127.0.0.1  4.newenergydata.info
> 127.0.0.1  4.periziavela.com
> 127.0.0.1  4.pianetapollo.com
> 127.0.0.1  4.whereinitaly.com
> 127.0.0.1  4.whereinlazio.com
> 127.0.0.1  4.whereinliguria.com
> ```

Format for get_tornodes:
[Tornodes](https://check.torproject.org/exit-addresses)

> ```
> ExitNode 0011BD2485AD45D984EC4159C88FC066E5E3300E
> Published 2016-11-15 07:22:42
> LastStatus 2016-11-15 08:03:23
> ExitAddress 162.247.72.201 2016-11-15 08:09:55
> ExitNode 004FDAC2B5B966F53361FA34D7E6E48D512FE869
> Published 2016-11-14 21:58:30
> LastStatus 2016-11-14 23:02:24
> ExitAddress 103.14.68.50 2016-11-14 23:06:35
> ExitNode 006CC1DD17754582618DE2539DAAFE0A96962583
> Published 2016-11-14 23:19:25
> LastStatus 2016-11-15 00:03:24
> ExitAddress 198.50.159.155 2016-11-15 00:03:42
> ExitNode 0077BCBA7244DB3E6A5ED2746E86170066684887
> Published 2016-11-14 23:28:32
> ```

Format for get_ransomewaretracker
[RWTcsvfile](https://ransomwaretracker.abuse.ch/feeds/csv/):

> ```
> ##############################################################################
> # Ransomware Tracker CSV Feed                                                #
> # Generated on 2016-11-15 15:26:56 UTC                                       #
> #                                                                            #
> # For questions please refer to:                                             #
> # https://ransomwaretracker.abuse.ch/feeds/                                  #
> ##############################################################################
> #
> # Firstseen (UTC),Threat,Malware,Host,URL,Status,Registrar,IP address(es),ASN(s),Country
> "2016-11-15 11:53:22","C2","Locky","185.82.217.29","http://185.82.217.29/message.php","offline","","185.82.217.29","59729","BG"
> "2016-11-15 10:07:59","Payment Site","TorrentLocker","ojmekzw4mujvqeju.minitili.at","http://ojmekzw4mujvqeju.minitili.at/","online","","95.163.118.67","207027|12695","RU"
> "2016-11-15 07:39:38","Payment Site","Cerber","ffoqr3ug7m726zou.ndnmuk.top","http://ffoqr3ug7m726zou.ndnmuk.top","offline","Eranet
>  International Limited","","34702",""
> "2016-11-15 02:48:56","C2","Locky","107.181.174.34","http://107.181.174.34/message.php","offline","","107.181.174.34","46562","US"
> "2016-11-14 19:15:48","C2","Locky","93.170.123.119","http://93.170.123.119/message.php","offline","","93.170.123.119","48666","CZ"
> "2016-11-14 11:15:34","Payment Site","Cerber","ffoqr3ug7m726zou.rssh3l.bid","http://ffoqr3ug7m726zou.rssh3l.bid","online","","104.238.215.11","36114","US"
> "2016-11-14 09:27:25","Payment Site","Cerber","ffoqr3ug7m726zou.2rl0pv.top","http://ffoqr3ug7m726zou.2rl0pv.top","offline","Eranet
>  International Limited","","36114",""
> "2016-11-14 06:45:30","Payment Site","Cerber","lfdachijzuwx4bc4.vrgdrs.top","http://lfdachijzuwx4bc4.vrgdrs.top","online","Eranet
>  International Limited","104.238.215.11|104.238.215.11|46.22.220.37","36114|34702","US|EE"
> "2016-11-14 04:11:26","Payment Site","Cerber","ffoqr3ug7m726zou.iocvou.top","http://ffoqr3ug7m726zou.iocvou.top","offline","Eranet
>  International Limited","","36114|34702",""
> "2016-11-14 01:16:46","Payment Site","Cerber","ahuqfrqk54v3vnzj.8kiec2.top","http://ahuqfrqk54v3vnzj.8kiec2.top","offline","Eranet
>  International Limited","","36114|34702",""
> "2016-11-14 00:58:48","Payment Site","Cerber","ffoqr3ug7m726zou.bwei9h.top","http://ffoqr3ug7m726zou.bwei9h.top","offline","Erane
> ```

Format for get_bambenek
[banbenek](https://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/feeds/c2-ipmasterlist.txt):

> ```
> ##############################################################################
> # Ransomware Tracker CSV Feed                                                #
> # Generated on 2016-11-15 15:26:56 UTC                                       #
> #                                                                            #
> # For questions please refer to:                                             #
> # https://ransomwaretracker.abuse.ch/feeds/                                  #
> ##############################################################################
> #
> # Firstseen (UTC),Threat,Malware,Host,URL,Status,Registrar,IP address(es),ASN(s),Country
> "2016-11-15 11:53:22","C2","Locky","185.82.217.29","http://185.82.217.29/message.php","offline","","185.82.217.29","59729","BG"
> "2016-11-15 10:07:59","Payment Site","TorrentLocker","ojmekzw4mujvqeju.minitili.at","http://ojmekzw4mujvqeju.minitili.at/","online","","95.163.118.67","207027|12695","RU"
> "2016-11-15 07:39:38","Payment Site","Cerber","ffoqr3ug7m726zou.ndnmuk.top","http://ffoqr3ug7m726zou.ndnmuk.top","offline","Eranet
>  International Limited","","34702",""
> "2016-11-15 02:48:56","C2","Locky","107.181.174.34","http://107.181.174.34/message.php","offline","","107.181.174.34","46562","US"
> "2016-11-14 19:15:48","C2","Locky","93.170.123.119","http://93.170.123.119/message.php","offline","","93.170.123.119","48666","CZ"
> "2016-11-14 11:15:34","Payment Site","Cerber","ffoqr3ug7m726zou.rssh3l.bid","http://ffoqr3ug7m726zou.rssh3l.bid","online","","104.238.215.11","36114","US"
> "2016-11-14 09:27:25","Payment Site","Cerber","ffoqr3ug7m726zou.2rl0pv.top","http://ffoqr3ug7m726zou.2rl0pv.top","offline","Eranet
>  International Limited","","36114",""
> "2016-11-14 06:45:30","Payment Site","Cerber","lfdachijzuwx4bc4.vrgdrs.top","http://lfdachijzuwx4bc4.vrgdrs.top","online","Eranet
>  International Limited","104.238.215.11|104.238.215.11|46.22.220.37","36114|34702","US|EE"
> "2016-11-14 04:11:26","Payment Site","Cerber","ffoqr3ug7m726zou.iocvou.top","http://ffoqr3ug7m726zou.iocvou.top","offline","Eranet
>  International Limited","","36114|34702",""
> "2016-11-14 01:16:46","Payment Site","Cerber","ahuqfrqk54v3vnzj.8kiec2.top","http://ahuqfrqk54v3vnzj.8kiec2.top","offline","Eranet
>  International Limited","","36114|34702",""
> "2016-11-14 00:58:48","Payment Site","Cerber","ffoqr3ug7m726zou.bwei9h.top","http://ffoqr3ug7m726zou.bwei9h.top","offline","Erane
> ```

Domains:
[Bambenekdomains](http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/feeds/c2-dommasterlist.txt)

> ```
> ###########################################################
> ## Master Feed of known, active and non-sinkholed C&Cs domain
> ## names
> ## 
> ## Feed generated at: 2016-11-15 15:16 
> ##
> ## Feed Provided By: John Bambenek of Bambenek Consulting
> ## jcb@bambenekconsulting.com // http://bambenekconsulting.com
> ## Use of this feed is governed by the license here: 
> ## http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/license.txt 
> ##
> ## For more information on this feed go to: 
> ## http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/manual/c2-dommasterlist.txt
> ## 
> ## All times are in UTC
> #############################################################
> ns1.backdates10.com,Domain used by beebone,2016-11-15 15:09,http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/manual/beebone.txt
> ns1.backdates2.com,Domain used by beebone,2016-11-15 15:09,http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/manual/beebone.txt
> ns1.backdates3.com,Domain used by beebone,2016-11-15 15:09,http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/manual/beebone.txt
> ns1.dnsfor15.com,Domain used by beebone,2016-11-15 15:09,http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/manual/beebone.txt
> ns1.dnsfor7.com,Domain used by beebone,2016-11-15 15:09,http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/manual/beebone.txt
> ns1.dnsfor8.com,Domain used by beebone,2016-11-15 15:09,http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/manual/beebone.txt
> g0spgts27johy2q.ddns.net,Domain used by corebot,2016-11-15 15:08,http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/manual/corebot.txt
> k016u4wdspqb10a.ddns.net,Domain used by corebot,2016-11-15 15:08,http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/manual/corebot.txt
> o8ehahitsbw0s07.ddns.net,Domain used by corebot,2016-11-15 15:08,http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/manual/corebot.txt
> jyalcixnmcjafecuk.net,Domain used by fobber,2016-11-15 15:09,http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/manual/fobber-iplist.txt
> suogzzicvq.com,Domain used by fobber,2016-11-15 15:09,http://osint.bambenekconsulting.com/manual/fobber-iplist.txt
> ```

Comment: "if needed I can paste a output from this feed." Please add example input data to give us something to test against.

Comment: @Mast i ended up adding outputs for all of them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your questions:

- See below, the code is *very* repetitive, so if you notice a case like
  that there's almost always a way to reduce the repetition.
- I'm not sure what you are concerned about, if you need to disable
  something temporarily consider `argparse` if you drive it from the
  commandline with feature flags.
- That seems sensible, normalising the input by stripping out whitespace
  is pretty common.

---

Other remarks about the code:

- Use `with` with `open` so that files are always closed.
- Using a class is fine I guess to keep things together, but seems a bit
  pointless given that it's mostly just procedural code.
- I'd probably remove all the temporary variables and inline things to
  save a few lines.
- The fixed URLs might be better off as constants grouped at the top.
- `d` is a global.  That's ... not good.  The one thing that really
  should be a member variable is not.  Consider moving that into the
  constructor if you keep it as a class.
- Even if the structure isn't exactly the same, at least extract some
  common code into separate methods, e.g.:

  ```
  def get_source(self, url, key):
      result = d[key]
      for line in self.download_file(url).splitlines():
          if len(line) > 0:
              if self.ipgrabber(line.lstrip().rstrip()):
                  result.append(line)
  ```

  or something along those lines.  I've put `result` at the start
  because it's a minor optimisation, it could be left in the inner loop
  in case you find it too verbose.
- The `main` method has what, about ten duplicate loops?  Again, extract
  the shared code with the name of the list as the parameter, e.g.:

  ```
  def write_list(self, f, key, name):
      f.write("".join("{}\t[{}]\n".format(t, name) for t in d[key]))
  ...
  # in main
      self.write_list(f, 'ransomwaretrackerdomain', 'Ransomewaretracker')
  ```
- Typo in `get_tornodes`, `if len(results) > 0:` should use `result`.
- The methods are all returning `d` for no reason.
- In `get_alienvault` the loop could be a bit simplified with a
  definition like the following (or with a `try/catch` for the
  `mapping[t]` access in case the key wasn't defined in `mapping`,
  but I dislike that pattern):

  ```
  mappings = {'IPv4': 'alienvaultip', 'URL': 'alienvaulturl', 'domain': 'alienvaultdomain'}
  for index, feeds in enumerate(pulses):
      for pulse in pulses[index]['indicators']:
          t = pulse['type']
          if t in mappings:
              d[mapping[t]].append(pulse['indicator'])
  ```

Comment: Il keep this short, since i dont have a lot of characters.
1. Was not really needed to be a class, it just started out that way, if there is no need for it, il remove it and save a few lines.
2. Which temp variables? And do you mean comments?
3. Okay il move up the urls, and rename them for each feed.
4. I guess d is not an issue anymore, as i move away from class.
5. I will try to see what i can do about getting it smaller, but that's why i came here.
6. Can i run all the functions in one loop?
7. I will remove the returns.
8. Okay, i change up the get_alienvault as well, to test

Comment: Okay, so i managed to figure it all out, except 2 things,
I did not manage to simplify `get_alienvault`..
I did not manage to simplify the write operations to file (though i did add `while` and removed f.close()
Would you be able to describe these two procedures?
I also tried to simplify the domain lists, but that was impossible, as they all have different filtering.

Comment: Added some more code, hope that helps.

Comment: just what i needed, thank's for clearing up the last points! This has been really helpful for me!
Last thing, i would still need to call all my functions like i do now right? I mean the full list i have at the start of my main().

Comment: Yes indeed, but this should get you thinking about how to restructure it, maybe put the parameters in a list and call the method in a loop with each of them, or something else ... usually data-driven is more flexible and a bit shorter than hard coding the function calls.